# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to NSLOG a NSSET in a managed object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a simple core data Object that will give me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` whenever I try to `NSLog` its contents in Xcode.

The managed object looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class ChatFriend, ChatMessage;

@interface ChatThread : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * threadId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *friends;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *messages;
@end

@interface ChatThread (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addFriendsObject:(ChatFriend *)value;
- (void)removeFriendsObject:(ChatFriend *)value;
- (void)addFriends:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeFriends:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addMessagesObject:(ChatMessage *)value;
- (void)removeMessagesObject:(ChatMessage *)value;
- (void)addMessages:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMessages:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

This is the `.m` file:

```
#import "ChatThread.h"
#import "ChatFriend.h"
#import "ChatMessage.h"


@implementation ChatThread

@dynamic threadId;
@dynamic timestamp;
@dynamic friends;
@dynamic messages;

- (NSString*) description
{

    /* This can print out the contents of self.messages correctly
    for(ChatMessage *message in self.messages)
    {
        Log(@"ChatMessage - %@", message);
    }
    */

    // using %@ to print out self.messages directly, will fail:
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ChatThread - threadId:%@, messages count:%d, messages:%@", self.threadId, self.messages.count, self.messages];
}

@end
```

I noticed that if I attempt to print out the contents of self.messages in the `stringWithFormat` line, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` will happen. If I remove self.messages, only print out the `self.messages.count`, it works. If I manually do a for loop to print out each message in the messages `NSSet`, it works and it proves that there are some values there.

So, why does printing self.messages directly will trigger `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: Strange. Does self.messages throw this exception even after you went through the loop and printed each member individually?

Comment: Any difference when you print [self.messages description] ?

Comment: I don't know it this explains the problem, but if this is an OS X app then `count` returns a `NSUInteger` which is 64-bit and should be printed with `%ld` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @MartinR: that shows a warning only but runs quite good. And his problem is with `self.messages` not with count!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: My idea was: If `self.count` pushes a `unsigned long` onto the stack, but `%d` expects only an `unsigned int`, then this might interfere with reading the remaining varargs.

Comment: Hi Hermann, yes self.messages still triggers the exception even after I went through the loop....

Comment: @MartinR's point regarding size is a good one, but the correct specifier is `%lu` for an `NSUInteger`, because `%ld` treats the value as signed (which would be `NSInteger`).

Comment: @PeterHosey: Yes of course. But somehow it doesn't seem to matter, I made a small test and the remaining arguments are passed without problem. I have to look up how variadic arguments are passed to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is extremely explicit when it comes to overriding `description` in an NSManagedObject:

> You can safely invoke the following methods on a fault without causing it to fire: isEqual:, hash, superclass, class, self, isProxy, isKindOfClass:, isMemberOfClass:, conformsToProtocol:, respondsToSelector:, description, managedObjectContext, entity, objectID, isInserted, isUpdated, isDeleted, faultingState, and isFault. Since isEqual and hash do not cause a fault to fire, managed objects can typically be placed in collections without firing a fault. Note, however, that invoking key-value coding methods on the collection object might in turn result in an invocation of valueForKey: on a managed object, which would fire the fault.
>
> Although the description method does not cause a fault to fire, if you implement a custom description method that accesses the object’s persistent properties, this will cause a fault to fire. You are strongly discouraged from overriding description in this way.

You appear to have violated the warning in that last paragraph.  Make your NSManagedObjectContext not return objects as faults, or use `valueForKey:` to fire the fault explicitly and load the resultant property before trying to to access it's description.  Faulted objects that fire themselves result in undefined behavior.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSet says it is.

Comment: hi, sorry i m still new in CoreData, what does "causing a fault to fire" means actually? I am guessing it means "causing the managed object to be loaded from persistent storage into memory?"

Comment: Yes.  And when you try to use the object format specifier, it's actually your first string property that's causing the fault to load itself.

Comment: @dunforget thank you for tolerating that dreadful first answer that I put up.  It was shameful that I could just one-off an answer as wrong as that.